# Java overloading with objects

Tags: java, overloading

I want to know why the second print statement produces "one implementation" as and output, below is the java code

```
    class Point {
    public boolean equals(final Object anObject) {
        System.out.println("One implementation.");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Point aPoint) {
        System.out.println("Another implementation.");
        return false;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Point p1 = new Point();
        final Point p2 = new Point();
        final Object o = p1;
        System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));
        System.out.println(o.equals(p2));
        System.out.println(p1.equals(o));
    }
}
```

The output:-

Another implementation

false

One implementation {concern}

false

One implementation

false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method

```
boolean equals(Object other);
```

overloads a base Object method; this method

```
boolean equals(Point other);
```

does not.  So, when you call `Object.equals()`, which is what you're doing in your second case, you will end up in the first implementation you provided.  Overriding `Object.equals()` is what you need to do as a minimum; other implementations are optional, and in my opinion, apt to mislead.

One should annotate overrides with `@Override`; this might help avoid confusion about whether a purported override really is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javap` utility with  `-c -v` flags to get better understanding what's going on, full command `javap -c -v Main`, its output (I truncated it) is

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Main$Point
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method Main$Point."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: new           #2                  // class Main$Point
      11: dup
      12: invokespecial #3                  // Method Main$Point."<init>":()V
      15: astore_2
      16: aload_1
      17: astore_3
      18: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      21: aload_1
      22: aload_2
      23: invokevirtual #5                  // Method Main$Point.equals:(LMain$Point;)Z
      26: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      29: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      32: aload_3
      33: aload_2
      34: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      37: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      40: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      43: aload_1
      44: aload_3
      45: invokevirtual #8                  // Method Main$Point.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      48: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      51: return
```

In other words, Java compiler translated 2nd invocation into `java/lang/Object.equals` because type of `o` variable is `Object`. Java is statically typed language so all type resolutions happen at compile time so it does not matter if variable `o` will be assigned `Point` at run-time